# Is There A Way to Have Excel Convert a Timestamp from OpenStack Creation Timestamp

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a crazy task whereby which I have to take the OpenStack Server Creation timestamps in the format of:

```
2020-03-30T20:27:06Z
```

It doesn't seem that Excel has the capability to convert this natively to an actual date.
But I need to do a time series analysis on it and need to format the date properly to an Excel Date/Time Format.

My question, is there a function and/or a way to split this into a date and time within Excel that uses a normal standard format?
Date:

```
MM/DD/YYYY
```

Time:

```
Military Time 2400
```

Comment: `=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," "),"Z","")`; https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKO77.png

Comment: Or: `=--REPLACE(LEFT(A1,19),11,1," ")`